# What does seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size) do in Python?

Tags: python

From nosklo's answer in [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) what is the return line doing:

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))
```

I understand what the output will be, I'd just like to know how this works.

EDIT: Adding use case to hopefully clear up confusion.

I am using the defined function to read in a list of unknown size and grab 8 objects from it, run those 8 through something, and then grab the next 8 and so forth until the list is completed. Use case from nosklo's post:

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'duck', 'bird', 'cow', 'gnu', 'fish']

for group in chunker(animals, 3):
    print group
# ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
# ['duck', 'bird', 'cow']
# ['gnu', 'fish']
```

Comment: This is a generator expression.

Comment: A good read https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(<expr> for <var> in <itr>)` is a generator expression. Equivalent to

```
def anon():
    for <var> in <itr>:
        yield <expr>
anon()
```

`seq[<start>:<stop>]` is slice notation. For lists, it will make a new list object with the elements in that range. Should have the same effect as `[seq[i] for i in range(<start>, <stop>)]`.

`range(<start>, <stop>, <step>)` is the range builtin. Generates an iterable of integers.

`len(seq)` length builtin. Same as `seq.__len__()`, which is supposed to get the "length" of the object. It's up to the object to decide what this means, but for sequence types like `list` it should be the number of elements.

Comment: Many thanks gilch. "seq[<start>:<stop>] is slice notation." is exactly the information I needed and thanks for taking the time to explain it all.